# Highlight duplicates at nearest distance

Tags: qgis, distance, expression, nearest-neighbor, duplication

I have a point shapefile with several names and there are a lot of duplicate names in the data.

I want to highlight the nearest duplicates in the data.

How can I solve that in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If you add what you mean by "highlighing" (where, what), I could add that to the solution. So far, the solution explains how to identify the nearest duplicate. Highlighing, once explained what you mean with that, should be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expressions to get for each point the id of the closest point with the same attribute value, like `name`.

You can use for this `overlay_nearest` function ([available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core), for older versions have a look at the [refFunctions Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/)).

1. It allows you to create an array of features, sorted in ascending order of distance to the current feature: nearest, second nearest etc.
2. Than filter this array for elements (features) with the same name as the current feature.
3. From the filtered array, get the first (=nearest) element.

The expression looks like this this - output is the id of the nearest point with the same value in the field `name`. Use this expression with field calculator to create a field `nearest_duplicate`:

```
array_first (
    array_filter( 
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            $id, 
            limit:= count(name)
        ),
        attribute( 
            get_feature_by_id (
                @layer, 
                @element
            ), 
            'name'
        ) = 
        attribute( 
            get_feature_by_id (
                @layer,
                $id 
            ), 
            'name'
        )
    )
)
```

*See screenshot: here, I used a slightly expanded version of the expression above to create connecting lines with geometry generator to visualize the connecting from each point to it's nearest duplicate:*
[image]

See the following screenshot where points are also numbered to be identified easier. Look for example at the bottom right, where you have three points named `C` - C:28, C:47 and C:19. Their respective nearest duplicate is as follows:

[image]

[image]